# Is it legal to meet with potential future employers in the UK, whilst visiting from the USA

Tags: uk, us-citizens

One of my friends from the USA will be visiting the UK at some point using her visa free travel, she has previously been here before over the last few years.

At some point in the future, she wants to move and work here, and wanted to know the legalities about meeting with potential employers when visiting us, if that is *not* her main purpose for the visit.

She isn't planning on actively handing out CV's and applying for actual jobs, she is more so interested in if she meets with people from companies, to build up a rapport, so she could then pursue a job with them in the future. For example, having coffee with a studio manager, or visiting a workplace.

Would these things be seen as straight up job hunting (therefore violating the terms of her visit) or not?

Comment: As far as I know job hunting is generally fine. What you should not do is **working**.

Comment: Though note that an immigration officer may be concerned that they will actively seek work there and then, rather than potentially in the future. As such, the circumstances probably make it more important than normal to be able to show you have reason to go home.

Comment: @Bakuriu agreed - this is "networking"

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This activity appears to be permitted in the UK, per [Home Office Immigration Rule Appendix V, Visitors Appendix 3 Section 5 (a)](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules).

> **Business - general activities**
>
> 5 A visitor may:
>
> (a) attend meetings, conferences, seminars, interviews;
>
> (c) negotiate and sign deals and contracts;
>
> (f) gather information for their employment overseas;

Answer (score 7):

Be careful.  One of the early episodes of *UK Border Force* featured an American?Canadian? Visitor who had a dozen copies of their CV in their suitcase.  Obviously there were other factors; that's how they arrived at the luggage search; but the CVs were the last nail in the coffin.

She was a professional worker and none of the factors suggested that she didnlt intend to get the correct visa before actually working, they did not like that looking was part of the reason for her visit.

Comment: I tend to agree. UK border control can be very snooty. They once tried to deny me boarding to USA because I only had 300 dollars in my pocket for a week visit to my sister. Advise your friend to come "on holidays" and leave their cv online.

Comment: Yeah, this is why she won't be bringing a CV of sorts. She's an actor so most of her work is online anyway. Thankfully she has visited several times before for sightseeing and festivals so she has experience dealing with what the border force are like

Comment: @vikingsteve - Your advice about leaving a CV at home/online is correct, in that the friend isn't actually intending to take employment. However your quoted purpose "on holidays" suggests that you are advising the OP to conceal their activities from the Immigration Officer. This is always bad advice. Never, **ever** lie to an IO. If you're ever found out, then not only will you be refused entry but you'll face a future **ban** from entering the country.

Comment: @vikingsteve How does the UK border force check you when leaving for the USA? Although exit checks were re-introduced in 2015, the airlines just report the exiting passengers to the offices using API. As https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/exit-checks-on-passengers-leaving-the-uk/exit-checks-fact-sheet says, "Most passengers will not notice any significant difference" to the situation before the exit checks and that has indeed been my experience so far.

Comment: This was years ago, but you often find people on US flights get extra questioning. This question was in the queue to the checkin desk at Heathrow. I felt the agent was looking for any excuse to catch me up on something (was I going to work in USA, did I have enough funds, was I going to return, etc)

Comment: @vikingsteve That was most likely not UK Immigration but a US agency. They do (and have done for years) pre-flight checking on passengers traveling to USA in many international airports. If I recall correctly countries whose citizens can travel to USA visa-free (like ESTA or Visa Waiver Program) must agree to those checks.

Comment: @vikingsteve Agreeing with others...  If you got the rubber hose before you boarded the plane, but walked off the plane with no barriers, that was the US government doing [preclearance](https://www.cbp.gov/border-security/ports-entry/operations/preclearance).  But feel free to blame UKVI :)  *Of course we don't have any preclearance locations in the UK, but whatevs...*

Comment: Yeah, print the CVs once you get where you're going.

Comment: @Harper my issue was not with the preclearance in itself, but with the *attitude* of the snooty border control employees in UK. For some reason they seem to take pleasure in being condescending and treating you like you are doing something wrong. If you tell them you are going to do job hunting in the UK, you are needlessly asking for trouble - and a possible denial into the UK.

Comment: Doesn't seem illegal if she is only networking and not actually giving any false information

Comment: @vikingsteve The point is you didn't talk with *British border control* (well at least not during preclearance for the US flight), so they surely couldn't have been rude to you.

Comment: @Voo I am merely guessing that vikingsteve hit US preclearance.  I could be wrong, *noting that there doesn't seem to be any US preclearance in the UK at this time*.  UKVI is constitutionally allowed to do exit controls, so it might be exactly what it says on the tin.

Comment: @Harper Interesting. Apparently there's very little preclearance in Europe at all. But who are those people who check your US visa/VWP data before you get on the plane? (separate from the check by the airline at check-in, although I guess it might be a second check by the airline itself?). Had that several times in Vienna and I assumed it was US border control, but Vienna doesn't have preclearance either.

Comment: @Voo Good point. Those are staff from the airline (sometimes USCIS staff are present to assist or train).  Airlines are obliged to check that you have the correct papers to enter a country. The airline must check your papers are in order before flying  you, or the fine is nasty.  (no fine if you merely botch your entry interview). Regardless, the airplane must fly you back ASAP, though they can try to bill you for that.  So that's not an exit control, that's an entry prescreening.

Comment: @vikingsteve as voo points out, this was probably not a UKVI exit interview, this was probably the *airline itself* doing prescreening to avoid nasty fines, and avoid cost of flying you back if refused. Prescreening is usually done by airline staff, but USCIS keeps a staff at foreign airports to assist and train airlines at that.  Maybe USCIS happened to be present (or the airline asked them to get involved to reduce their liability).

Comment: Pardon ignorance, but is *UK Border Force* meant to be an accurate and complete representation of the behaviors or practices of the actual Border Force?

Comment: @dwizum that seems like "assassination by impossible standard": Is it *complete* does it show *every single UKVI interaction that ever was*? Imma go with "no". Is it *accurate* **in other words "are the events depicted in the show *staged* by actors under no real peril?"** I supremely doubt it.  Are they *cherry-picked*? Certainly for drama value or legal reasons e.g. consent to be filmed, but I believe that's more up to the producers than UKVI.  Obviously the producers want to be *invited back* so they won't do an expose on UKVI...

Comment: Fair enough. To be clear, my real questions were: is it an accurate representation of what you can expect to happen to you, if you're in the same circumstance? And, is it a complete enough representation that we can home in on this single point, or could there have been more factors that caused this to happen? I'm just trying to get a mental picture of this particular show and understand why it's reference-worthy; having seen other law-enforcement reality shows it seems that they run the gamut from "this is how it actually works" to "this is sensationalized entertainment".